# Referencing a TableViewController property when it is buried on a NavigationController stack

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, properties, uitableview

I have a UINavigationController with two UITableViewControllers pushed onto its stack.  Is there any way to reference a property on the first TableViewController that is under the second?  I would like to do this in the second controller's viewWillAppear method.

Thank you for any help you can give....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out it is...

```
[[[[self navigationController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] MyProperty];
```

index could be any number on the stack... Mine happens to be the first one so its index is 0...